# Cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (150,5)

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

## Cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (150,5)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
iris=np.array(iris)
iris.reshape(150, 5)
```

Comment: Could you share the error message?

Comment: `load_iris()['data']`

Comment: check the solution I've posted.

Comment: Reread the docs for `https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_iris.html`, `load_iris`.  You can't simply wrap the returned dictionary in `np.array`

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris().data
iris=np.array(iris)
print(iris.shape)

#(150,4)
```

you're retrieving the whole specs and data of iris dataset and passing that dictionary into numpy that's why it is giving error.

use iris.data instead.